# Why is there stack corruption with my visitor for my std::variant

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, stack, c++17

I struggle to understand what is happening with this snippet of code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

template <class... Ts>
struct overloaded : Ts... {
    using Ts::operator()...;
};
template <class... Ts>
overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

struct FirstPSet {
    std::uint16_t uid;
};

struct SecondPSet {
    std::uint16_t uid;
};

using PSet = std::variant<std::monostate, FirstPSet, SecondPSet>;

auto getUID(const PSet& pSet) {
    auto visitor = overloaded{[](const std::monostate&) -> std::uint16_t { return 0; },
                              [](const auto& pSet) -> std::uint16_t { return pSet.uid; }};
    return std::visit(visitor, pSet);
}

int main() {
    FirstPSet pSet{42};

    std::cout << getUID(pSet) << '\n';
}
```

When compiled with Visual Studio Community 16.8.2 (debug build), I have a exception for a stack corruption at the end of `getUID`.
If i modify `visitor`to be `auto&& visitor = ...`, it works fine.

Comment: This *looks* like a case of `visitor` being a temporary object, with its lifetime being extended by forcing the "rvalue reference." Not sure, though, and I can't reproduce with VS 16 (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: This works fine with GCC 11 . You can take the `std::monostate` out of the `tuple` and lambda. It is only needed if the first variant is not default constructable.

Comment: It works fine in Visual Studio Community 16.11.2 (debug build), so it looks like a compiler bug has been fixed.

Comment: Still crashing on Visual Studio Community 16.11.4 Preview 1 for me.

Comment: Seems to be this bug: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/runtime-stack-corruption-using-stdvisit/346200.